# How to get the KY-022 Infrared Receiver module to work on NodeMCU in Lua?

Tags: module, lua, nodemcu, infrared

I have a KY-022 IR module that I can't get to work on my NodeMCU. I've been searching for some code samples in Lua on the internet with no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any code samples would be greatly appreciate it.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
local pin = 4
gpio.mode(pin, gpio.OPENDRAIN, gpio.PULLUP)
gpio.trig(pin, "down", function (level, micro)
    print(gpio.read(pin), level, micro)
end)
```

When I press a button on the remote, I get something like this:

`0  0   571940709
0   0   571954086
0   0   571955257
1   0   571958694
1   0   571963275
1   0   571969917
0   0   571974347
0   0   571980989
1   0   571983203
1   0   571987709
0   0   571993359
1   0   572000078
0   0   572004508
0   0   572047513
0   0   572058674`

So, how do I get from that to figuring out which key was pressed on the remote?

After a month or so i've reopened this project and played around with it some more. As piglet suggested, I started listening for both high and low signals. The data is still very inconsistent and can't get a stable reading.

(And by the way, thanks for the vote-down piglet, that was greatly appreciated. I wish you could have seen my search history before you decided that i'm ignorant)

I'm going to post my curent code maybe somebody can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
local pin = 4
local prevstate = false
local prevmicro = 0
local prevtime = 0
local count = 0

gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT)
gpio.trig(pin, "both", function (level, micro)
    --local state = gpio.read(pin)
    local state = level
    if (micro - prevmicro) > 90000 then
        prevmicro = 0
        prevstate = false
        count = 0
        print("\n#", "st", "lv", "microtime", "timing")
    end
    if prevstate ~= state then
        time = math.floor((micro - prevmicro)/100)
        prevstate = state
        prevmicro = micro
        if time > 3 and time < 1000 then
            if prevtime > 80 and prevtime < 100 then
                if time > 17 and time < 25 then
                    print('Repeat')
                elseif time > 40 and time < 50 then
                    print('Start')
                end
            else
                print(count, gpio.read(pin), level, micro, time)
                count = count + 1
            end
            prevtime = time
        end
    end
end)
```

and here are some sample readouts from pushing the same button:

```
#   st  lv  microtime   timing
1   1   1   1504559531  16
2   1   0   1504566995  74
3   0   1   1504567523  5
4   1   0   1504573619  60
5   0   1   1504587422  138
6   1   0   1504588011  5
7   1   1   1504604250  162
8   1   0   1504605908  16
9   1   1   1504659929  540
10  1   0   1504662154  22

#   st  lv  microtime   timing
1   1   1   1505483535  16
2   1   0   1505491003  74
3   0   1   1505491558  5
4   1   0   1505497627  60
5   0   1   1505511409  137
6   1   0   1505512023  6
7   1   1   1505518186  61
8   1   0   1505527733  95
9   1   0   1505586167  22
10  1   1   1505586720  5

#   st  lv  microtime   timing
1   1   1   1507990937  16
2   1   0   1507998405  74
3   0   1   1507998934  5
4   1   0   1508005029  60
5   0   1   1508018811  137
6   1   0   1508019424  6
7   1   1   1508035641  162
8   1   0   1508037322  16
9   1   1   1508091345  540
10  1   0   1508093570  22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the Lua code required for this is actually quite simple.

Where the code above is falling over is actually the print statements. These are extremely expensive and basically, kill your sampling resolution until it's useless.

You are in essence, writing an interrupt service routine, you have a limited time budget before you have to read the next edge change and if it happens before you are done processing, tough luck! So you need to make the ISR as efficient as you can.

In the example below, we listen to the "both" edge event, when one occurs, we simply record an indication of which edge and what duration.

Periodically (using a timer) we print out the contents of the waveform.

This perfectly matches the waveform on my logic analyzer, you still have the challenge of decoding the signal. Though, there are lots of great protocol docs that explain how to take accurate waveform data and use it to determine the signal being sent. I found that a lot of cheap "brand x" remotes appear to be using the NEC protocol, so this might be a good place to start depending on your project.

IR transmission because of its nature is not completely error-free so you may get a spurious edge signal from time to time but the code below is pretty stable and runs quite well in isolation, I have yet to test it when the Microcontroller is under more load than just listening for IR.

It may turn out that using Lua for this purpose is not the best due to the fact that it is an interpreted language (each command issued is parsed and then executed at runtime, this is not at all efficient.) But I will see how far I can get before I decide to write a c module.

```
local irpin = 2
local lastTimestamp = 0
local waveform = {}
local i = 1

gpio.mode(irpin,gpio.INT)
gpio.trig(irpin, "both", function(level, ts)
    onEdge(level, ts)
end)

function onEdge(level, ts)
    waveform[i] = level
    waveform[i+1] = ts - lastTimestamp
    lastTimestamp = ts
    i = i+2   
end

-- Print out the waveform
function showWaveform ()
    if table.getn(waveform) > 65 then
        for k,v in pairs(waveform) do
            print(k,v)
        end
        i = 1;
        waveform = {}
    end
end
tmr.alarm(0, 1000, 1, showWaveform)

print("Ready")
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-dept analysis Paul. I will definately try your example code and get back to you with an upvote if it works. Also, i will try mine without the printing just to see if that changes anything. You might be on to something there ;)

Comment: Your code works like a charm! I modified the showWaveForm function so that it prints out the values in a single line, and now i can identify each button just by looking at it. So there is definatley a clear pattern I can work with. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you post some of the console output, maybe I can help you to identify which protocol it's using, the details of the protocol are quite interesting sometimes, especially if you want to generate new signals.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. That won't be necessary at the moment because i'm only intending to use it one way. Just to control a microcontroller with it so i don't really care about standards and protocols at the moment. Printing out the timings (which are consistent now thanks to you), is enough to identify each button and even to figuring out a way to lock out all other IR signals coming from other remotes. Now i can clearly recognize the "begin", "end" and "repeat" signals too. Eventually i'll work my way up to writing a library to handle more protocols. I'll post it here after it's done.

Comment: Thanks, the code was a godsend!

I've found with recent changes to the timer library the second to last line should read:
`tmr.create():alarm(1000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, showWaveform)`

Source: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/tmr/

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for my 17 key remote which came with my cheap KY-022 module. I just finished it and haven't had time to clean it up nor to optimize it, so bear with me.

```
local IR = 2
local lts, i, wave = 0, 0, {}

local keys = {}
keys['10100010000000100000100010101000'] = '1'
keys['10001010000000100010000010101000'] = '2'
keys['10101010000000100000000010101000'] = '3'
keys['10000010000000100010100010101000'] = '4'
keys['10000000000000100010101010101000'] = '5'
keys['10101000000000100000001010101000'] = '6'
keys['10101010000000000000000010101010'] = '7'
keys['10100010001000000000100010001010'] = '8'
keys['10100000100000000000101000101010'] = '9'
keys['10100000101000000000101000001010'] = '0'
keys['10001010001000000010000010001010'] = '*'
keys['10100010100000000000100000101010'] = '#'
keys['10000000101000000010101000001010'] = 'U'
keys['10000000100000000010101000101010'] = 'L'
keys['10001000101000100010001000001000'] = 'R'
keys['10001000001000100010001010001000'] = 'D'
keys['10000010101000000010100000001010'] = 'OK'

local function getKey()
    local data = ''
    local len = table.getn(wave)
    if len >= 70 then

        local pkey = 0
        local started = false
        for k, v in pairs(wave) do
            v = math.floor(v/100)
            if (pkey == 87 or pkey == 88 or pkey == 89) and (v > 40 and v < 50) then
                started = true
            end
            pkey = v
            if started then
                if v > 300 then
                    started = false
                end
                --this is just to fix some random skipped edges
                if (v > 20 and v < 25) or v == 11 then
                    if v > 20 and v < 25 then
                        d = 17
                    else
                        d = 6
                    end
                    v1 = v - d
                    data = data .. '' .. math.floor(v1/10)

                    v2 = v - (v - d)
                    data = data .. '' .. math.floor(v2/10)
                else
                    if v < 40 then
                        data = data .. '' .. math.floor(v/10)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        control = data:sub(0, 32)
        if control == '00000000000000000101010101010101' then
            data = data:sub(32, 63)
            print(len, data, keys[data] or '?')
        end
    end
    lts, i, wave = 0, 0, {}
end

local function onEdge(level, ts)
    local time = ts - lts
    wave[i] = time
    i = i + 1
    if time > 75000 then
        tmr.alarm(0, 350, 0, getKey)
    end
    lts = ts
end

gpio.mode(IR,gpio.INT)
gpio.trig(IR, "both", onEdge)
```

I'm putting this asside and start working on some other parts of my project for the moment, but if anyone has any suggestions on how I could improve it, make it faster, smaller even, leave a comment.

PS: for those that are going to complain about not working for them, you need to adjust the if statement values for the `started` variable based on your remote timings. In my case it's always 88 or 89 followed by 44.

Comment: Nice! I also found that I get intermittent skipped edges.

I checked the pins of the IR receiver with a logic analyser and found that this is actually due to the microcontroller missing the edge somehow and not the receiver hardware.

My theory is that Lua is simply not efficient enough to avoid this problem.

For the project I am working on, I require things to be more consistent than that and am working on modifying the nodemcu-firmware GPIO handling slightly so that it can run native c code for the ISR. My next step will be to write the ISR in C to see if the accuracy goes up.

Comment: @PaulMaidment Yeah, toatally agree. I'm retiring the IR remote because as soon as i run some other code, it just stops working. The microcontroller (basicly Lua) is just too slow to handle that. I have actually created an 8 button keypad that runs on two wires (one digital and one analog) so i'll just use that instead for this project.

Comment: I think the main reason NodeMCU is slow for applications like IR is that it runs a Lua interpreter, it is really cool that this allows you to test code over the serial port and so on, really handy for rapid iteration but terrible for efficiency.

Options for efficient IR, as I see it, are as follows

1) Modify nodemcu-firmware and write a custom IR module that runs in native c (for now the option I am attempting)
2) Use a lower level SDK such as the arduino tools, for more information see here

https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap01%20-%20ESP8266.html

Comment: Actually found this, a nice speed comparison of various MCU's

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q2sw0MpcFv1gNyNW6l9PZ8BvWq_LD0MqCEpUUKcegLE/edit#gid=0

8266 is a lot faster than the ATMega328 and that can sample multiple channels of IR while doing other stuff.

Comment: Confirmed, not quite ready to post code yet as the solution has a couple of moving parts that are not simple to describe, however, using a native c ISR to capture the edges, I got 100% accuracy in the measurements I made.

So my recommendation for IR is to read it using C code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the sequence sent by the remote for each button.

Record the IR emitter's on-off sequence by logging the time stamps for high-low and low-high transitions.

Note the various patterns for each button you want to use or emulate.

Here's a in-depth tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Useemulate-remotes-with-Arduino-and-Raspber/

You can find this and similar resources using www.google.com

Comment: yes, i know how to use google but i did mention that i wanted it in lua for my nodemcu. I found a bunch of resources for arduino and raspberry but nothing for what i need unfortunately.

Comment: @JoeBlack you cannot request code here. this is not a coding service. you're on a good way. getting the "down" events only is not enough. you need to know the low and high interval lenghts to derive a bit pattern

Comment: i've been trying to do that all day, believe me, but i'm getting very inconsistent readings even when i'm pushing the same button on the remote. i just can't find a pattern.